# How to modify a Minecraft ore lamp to be always on?

Tags: led, wiring

Santa was kind enough to bring a really cool diamond ore lamp for Christmas!:)

It's supposed to work by tapping it to turn it on, tap it again - it increases the brightness etc. The problem is that it shuts off really quickly and the tapping is *really* inconsistent, so I would rather have it just be always on and bypass the whole tapping thing altogether.

It works with 2 AA batteries and there's a switch to turn the thing on. I'd like to wire the switch directly to the LEDs, but if I remember correctly - I need to use resistors as well? Would anyone know what kind I need or maybe I can use the board to somehow utilize its components?..

Thanks and happy holidays everyone!

[image]

Comment: So you tap it, it turns on for some time, then turns itself off again? I would find where the tap triggers the one-shot timer, and then tie that input to a switch or similar to ensure it is always 'triggered'.

Comment: @KrunalDesai - That would be cool, but I'm afraid my knowledge about electrical circuits isn't that great to pull that off. I'd be very happy with the main switch just turning the LEDs on and off, bypassing the entire tapping circuit. I'm just not sure what resistors I would need, and if I can utilize the board itself

Comment: @KrunalDesai - I just thought that maybe your suggestion wouldn't work. There are 3 brightness levels. When powered the LEDs are off, and it takes 3 (more like 30) taps to reach its max brightness. So if I somehow tied the tapping trigger to wherever it goes, it would constantly cycle between the 4 modes (off and 3 brightness levels). Right?..

Comment: Please post the schematic.

Comment: Oh, I see -- you just want a switch to turn on and off all the LEDs inside the ornament. Do you have access to a multimeter? That will help us find the forward voltage drop of the LEDs -- are they white? There's no schematic available for this, so reversing it out will be needed.

Comment: @KrunalDesai - I don't have a multimeter..... I should really get one :/ The LEDs are blue. Edit: I'll be visiting my in-laws, they have a multimeter for sure. What what I need to do in order to test .. whatever I need to test. I'm so sorry for my newb-ness.... Oh and yes - just having the switch turn the LEDs on or off would be perfect

Comment: The best chance we stand of answering your question (and it not getting closed) is for you to provide a schematic for us. I bet that is a simple two layer board. Use the DMM in continuity mode to 'beep' out what everything on the PCB is connected too, and draw that out on paper. We're experienced enough here that we can pick up any small mistakes you make beeping it out as it's not an exotic topology of some type. Be sure to write down the reference designators (R1, R2, C2, etc.) of the parts as you trace them.

Comment: @KrunalDesai - is that really necessary for just wiring the switch to the LEDs directly?.. I thought resistors in between the batteries and the LEDs would be sufficient.

Comment: If that's what you'd like to do and ignore any of the 'smarts' of the part, all you would need to know is the rough forward voltage drop of the LEDs, and then use a simple LED calculator. I don't know how much current they require, so I'd start with a large resistor and work my way up.

Comment: Looks like there is an inductor at the top right of the board, so it is more than likely there is some DC/DC converter. Question is: is it a step up, a step down converter or is it configured for constant current? Next question: Can it be re-used?

Comment: I wonder nobody already complained...  For a good understanding of your problem, it's absolutely necessary to post a picture of the fully assembled device, may be while in operation in this special case :D

Comment: If your okay with cutting out the circuit board and a single half brightness,  I'll post a quick answer. All you would need is four resistors. A bit more advanced you would need a 1xAA battery holder as well

Comment: It uses 2x AA batteries so how long is this lamp going to shine when you convert it to have an on/off switch. Do some research on AA batteries and generic blue LEDs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick an easy mod, if you cut out the circuit. ***This will make the circuit inoperable and would need rewiring to work again.*** Won't be full brightness due to the blue led typical forward voltage and the 3V battery source.

[image]

Cut the led wires off. Cut the black wire for the switch (Marked SW). Cut the Ground circuit trace on the board Next to the SS14 Diode marked D5. This may not be needed, but between removing the SW black wire and cutting the ground, the entire circuit on the board is removed.

Since it's 3V with a blue led, you could hook it up directly, but don't want to risk it, so lets choose a safe resistor value. Blue leds work great with a cr2032 coin cell battery, because the battery has a ~20Ω internal equivalent series resistance (ESR). AA batteries do not. A 20Ω resistor will result in ~10mA or so. **It's not exactly a common setup, and it's hard to graph out the numbers like this**.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2faAKcl.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

So we should use a 20Ω resistor. Use one resistor per led. The Black SW wire goes to the Four Resistors. Each Resistor to a Red LED Wire. The Black LED wires to the point labeled GND. Now the switch will turn them on and off. No timer.

If you feel fancy, and want a brighter Cube, then you will also need an 1xAA battery holder. RadioShack, eBay, etc. Get the one with wires.

[image]

Since we increased the voltage, to better meet the LED's forward voltage drop, we need to calculate a new resistor. With 4.5V, and a typical 3.3V Forward Voltage, using Ohm's law `R = V/I` we get:

> (4.5V Source - 3.3V Forward Voltage Drop) / 0.020 Amps = 60 Ohms

The next standard resistor is 62Ω. At 19.3mA (Adjusting for the the 62Ω resistor), 4 leds, that's 77.2mA. Standard AA alkaline battery capacity is 2500mAh, so this setup will last for `2500mAh / 77.2mA = 33.2 hours.` If you increase the resistor a bit, the battery life will increase as well. 100Ω resistor, ~12 mA, and you will get 52 hours straight.

The change is minimal. You simply add the battery between the black led wires and the ground, and have it sit in the middle of the cube. *Of course this means having to open the cube to change the batteries.* This places the battery in series to create the 4.5V volts required for full blue led brightness. Remember the different size resistors.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fB12xf.png)</sup>

A small section of strip or proto board may help.

Comment: Thank you! I'm just wondering about your comment that the LEDs won't achieve full brightness. Will they be as bright as they can be with the circuit in place, or will the brightness drop lower than currently possible with the circuit?

Comment: @Matt not knowing how bright each of the steps the current board allows, I can't say. The 2 battery option should be brighter than the lowest setting, while the 3 battery option should be as bright as the brightest setting, assuming they are running the leds at the *typical normal current (20mA) for a random blue led* with no multiplex/scanning trickery.

Comment: very inefficient (3bat) or unregulated (2bat) method. better to use the boost regulator inside.

Answer (score 4):

I just eliminated  the 555 micro controller in the middle, by removing it and connecting the ground directly to the chip side of the existing resistors on the board I now have a cube that simply turns on and off with the switch, no more timer, the tap thing is bypassed, and the led's are at the brightest settings  ////PS the thick red wire from the ground to the chip is a testing wire I used to find the LED's, its just a loose wire

[image]

---

Im not an electronics guy, so its ugly, but it works , Nothing a ball of tin and flux cant fix lol

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qsh6K.jpg]

Edit: 48 hours later of nonstop use, the lights are still as bright as when I first turned it on  [image]

Edit again, 72 hours of nonstop use, and its finally starting to dim a bit... So 72 hours of continuous use before  ( in my case 2 energizer 2500 mah AA rechargeables ) need to be replaced

One last thing, I just got the blue version, and the circuit board is more like the one the original poster posted, and i did the same mod with the center chip and it worked fine as well

[image]

But the LED's on the blue one were still pretty dim, so just on the blue ones with this board I needed to cross this black with this red one.. the blue lights give off the medium setting of the unmodded cube, unlike the red one with the different board, that gives full high setting for the LED's

[image]...

Answer (score -1):

Blue LEDs usually require a bit more than 3 V to drive enough current through them to operate brightly. Your lamp has a switching chip to boost the voltage from the nominal 3 V supplied by the battery. The inductor coil L1 (black cylinder, upper right) is one of the giveaways for this.

The 8-pin chip is possibly a small micro. It's feeding each of the LED black wires individually and is monitoring the vibration switch (sticking out on the left). If it's a micro we won't be able to re-program it.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNHnQw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The simplified schematic above is what I can make out from the photo. (Anyone can edit if they can add more.) V1 represents the output of the voltage booster. The chip turns on each LED by connecting it's resistor to negative supply.

I suspect that you could desolder each LED black wire and solder a resistor from each LED black wire to GND (bottom right) and it would work.

Homework: when you get access to the multimeter measure the voltage between GND and  one of the LED red wires. Test it at each brightness setting and record the results. Report back and we'll update this answer. Wait for a few comments on this suggestion before you proceed with soldering.

Comment: The inductor is top right. The black thing at the left is a motion switch.

Comment: Now why didn't I read the silk screen properly! I'll fix my answer, thanks.

Comment: You could replace the motion sensor with a normal push button for more reliable operation.

Comment: 3 volts is good enough for bright bright blue. Even with just a cr2032.

Comment: I was thinking the SOIC was a SMPS / LED controller IC actually, but no reason a simple micro couldn't do that also

Comment: 3V is enough for blue LED's, but 2xAA is not good for 3V except when fresh. I believe the SOIC is a 4 channel LED boost regulator.

Comment: Perhaps a simpler option would be to just replace the flaky "tap" switch with a less flaky switch. Ah, Peter Bennett already said that...

Comment: Considering the LED's are around 15 Ω , the 1 Ω parts don't do much.  Plus the boost regulator is defeated so brightness decays quickly within a day. -1